# SSH with two different interfaces

Tags: networking, ssh, centos

I have two different network interfaces in my machine. One is eth0 which has the public IP address and other is eth0.1 which is a GRE tunnel setup over eth0. I have added IP address 192.168.1.1 to eth0.1 and I want to be able to ssh to this IP from other machine.

I have setup ssh so that I can ssh to this machine using its public IP address however I am not able to ssh using 192.168.1.1 address.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you certain GRE tunnel is correctly configured (addresses, routing). Can you send and receive ICMP packets between the devices (ping each other)? Also check if `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has both interface addresses allowed.

Comment: @MarekRost: Yes, I have confirmed that. I am able to ping packets between eth0.1 IP addresses. Can you please explain more about `sshd_config` entries? I don't have any such entries

Comment: `ListenAddress` in `sshd_config` should be listed either twice with IP of both `eth0` and `eth0.1` or set to `0.0.0.0` or completly omitted. (if you haven't touched that option before, then it's most likely ok). Check firewall if you don't have rules declared for `eth0` explictly?

Comment: @MarekRost: Issue resolved! I added an extra ListenAddress entry for IP address of eth0.1 and now sshd listens on both IP addresses. Thanks!

Comment: @MarekRost As this solves the issue, you can add this as an answer.